# How can I hide the <ul> tag without having to modify the HTML using only CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a question with the following HTML: how can I hide the `<ul>` tag without having to modify the HTML using only CSS?

```css
.principal input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+#menuPrincipal {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}

.principal input[type="checkbox"]:checked+#menuPrincipal {
  transition: height 0.6s ease;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="principal">
    <input type="checkbox" name="menuCheck" id="menuCheck">
    <label for="menuCheck" aria-role="button"></label>
    <ul id="menuPrincipal">
      <li><a href="">enlace 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">enlace 2</a></li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="submenuCheck" id="submenuCheck">
        <label for="submenuCheck" aria-role="button">enlace 3</label>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub Enlace 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Enlace 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: `ul { display: none }` ? or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @mb21 but the it will hide second checkbox too? i think user needs to specific about his issue.

Answer (score 1):

As it is not the direct next sibling you would have to use a tilde `~` instead of a plus, otherwise you would have to remove the label in between the `input` and the `ul`

I would also move your transition onto the `ul` so it transitions both ways rather than just when it is going from checked to unchecked.

```css
#menuPrincipal {
  transition: height 0.6s ease;
}

.principal input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)~#menuPrincipal {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}

.principal input[type="checkbox"]:checked~#menuPrincipal {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="principal">
    <input type="checkbox" name="menuCheck" id="menuCheck">
    <label for="menuCheck" aria-role="button"></label>
    <ul id="menuPrincipal">
      <li><a href="">enlace 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">enlace 2</a></li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="submenuCheck" id="submenuCheck">
        <label for="submenuCheck" aria-role="button">enlace 3</label>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub Enlace 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub Enlace 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```